# Soft key buttons

Tags: android

We are trying to build an android app to serve as a remote control for a robot. We have the code pretty much completed but there is a problem about holding the keys. We used soft key as the basic structure of the app and we modified it so that the direction pad can control the robot remotely. However there is a problem in our code. When we press (for example) the "up" button, the app continuously sends out the "up" signal even after we release the key. Is there a way that we can stop the signal once we release the button? Please advice, Thanks for your help in advance.

A section of our code:

```
private boolean genericClick( View v, boolean longClick, MotionEvent me ) {
        if( me != null ) {
            Toast.makeText( this, "Warning: MotionEvent is broken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
        }

        // send an intent to the main window
        int keyid = 0;
        Globals app = (Globals)getApplication();
        boolean hide = auto_hide;

        switch( v.getId() ) {
            case R.id.home:
                Log.v("MyActivity", "Wifi");        


try {  

s = new Socket("142.58.160.178", 5000);


   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));


   writer.write("Connect");

   writer.flush();

   writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

} catch (UnknownHostException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block





           Toast.makeText( this, "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG );

e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {


// TODO Auto-generated catch block

           Toast.makeText( this, "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG );

e.printStackTrace();



}


                //app.doHomeAction( longClick );
                break;

            case R.id.extra_center:
                keyid = K.KEYID_DPAD_CENTER;
                //Log.v("MyActivity", "stop");
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);
                hide = false;
                break;

            case R.id.extra_up:
                keyid = K.KEYID_DPAD_UP;
                //Log.v("MyActivity", "up1");
                direction=0; //up
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);
                mHandler.postAtTime(mUpdateTask, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 50);
                hide = false;
                break;

            case R.id.extra_down:
                keyid = K.KEYID_DPAD_DOWN;
                //Log.v("MyActivity", "down1");
                direction=1;    


                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);
                mHandler.postAtTime(mUpdateTask, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 50);
                hide = false;
                break;

            case R.id.extra_left:
                keyid = K.KEYID_DPAD_LEFT;
                //Log.v("MyActivity", "left1");
                direction=2;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);
                mHandler.postAtTime(mUpdateTask, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 50);
                hide = false;
                break;

            case R.id.extra_right:
                keyid = K.KEYID_DPAD_RIGHT;
                //Log.v("MyActivity", "right1");
                direction=3;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);
                mHandler.postAtTime(mUpdateTask, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 50);
                hide = false;
                break;
}
}

private Runnable mUpdateTask = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            switch(direction){
            case 0:
                Log.i("repeatBtn", "Up");          

if (s!=null){            

    try {

   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

   writer.write("U");

   writer.flush();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {        

     // TODO Auto-generated catch block

     e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

     // TODO Auto-generated catch block

     e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

    break;
            case 1:
              // Log.i("repeatBtn", "Down");          

if (s!=null){

    try {

   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

   writer.write("D");

   writer.flush();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {        

     // TODO Auto-generated catch block

     e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

     // TODO Auto-generated catch block

     e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

    break;
            case 2:
               // Log.i("repeatBtn", "Left");  

if (s!=null){                

    try {

   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

   writer.write("L");

   writer.flush();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {        

     // TODO Auto-generated catch block

     e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

     // TODO Auto-generated catch block

     e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

break;

            case 3:
               // Log.i("repeatBtn", "Right");          

if (s!=null){              

    try {

   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

   writer.write("R");

   writer.flush();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {        


     // TODO Auto-generated catch block


     e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {


     // TODO Auto-generated catch block


     e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

break;

            }

            mHandler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 50);      

        }
    };
```

Comment: Are you _really_ connecting to a socket in a click handler? I'd like to run your code through `Lindent` so it is more legible, but I won't bother until I find out whether or not that is a simple pasting error or you're actually connecting to a socket in a button click handler.

Comment: Just curious, is this for FRC?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no code that actually removes the callback once and for all, except for when pressing the center key. At the end of mUpdateTask, the callback injects itself into the Handler queue again, which explains the repetition.

If you want to be able to send the events for as long as the button is pressed, it's an idea to use an OnTouchListener for the buttons, as it can react both to presses and release. An OnClickListener can only react to a press + release.